# The reverse name YHWH not for Adar?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, prayer-book, shemos-sacred-names, adar, months

As most of us know, each month has a combination of the holy name YHWH - that's 3 letters YHW  times 4 places gives 12 combinations. It is intended to be kept in mind while saying the Brocho of Musaf for every Rosh Chodesh.

The reverse name (ונהפוך הוא) is HWHY and a Pasuk it is learned from is "זה איננו שווה לי" - that's the last letters abbreviation - the Posuk from Meggilat Ester.

We would all expect those letters would stand for the month of Adar but... No, it stands for Tamuz instead.

Please explain how it relates to Tamuz and not Adar.

Here's a page of an "Ar"i Siddur":

[image]

Comment: I bet most people don't know that

Comment: @DoubleAA You are correct in regard to your first comment. but if Al Berko has a real question in regard to this subject, he should look at Sefer Pardes Rimonim from Rabbi Moshe Cordevero. It is discussed there.

Comment: I've deleted all of the comments regarding casual suggestions about such analysis being objectionable, as they have no bearing on improving the post.

Comment: "that's 3 letters YHW times 4 places gives 12 combinations": that's not how it works. If there were two different letters occupying three places, you'd not have six combinations.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Or Dvar Yom BYomo.